# SQL Queries - 2 Different questions with different responses in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Currently I have data with responses from questions, that is already stored in tables. 
The first question ask a yes or no question, then the users were directed to another question that was either a yes or no, or had a few different answer choices.

Basically the idea is to see that if someone answered yes or no on the first question are they more likely to have a certain response on the next question.

Is there a way to create a query that always has the first question with the yes or no responses and then can intake different second questions that have different outputs (yes, no, other, etc)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: Given time and budget, almost anything is possible. A web form with SQL queries to handle yes/no responses does not take long and is not expensive.

Comment: It's a simple self-join

Comment: So I would need to self-join to the other tables (the one that has the second group of questions and then join that table to the second group of answer) ? How would I make it where the column names (can change based on the question used)? I guess what I'm trying to ask is there a way to have the columns names be mutable based on the question that is used?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query